# Same scene 1 GPU = OK, 2 GPUs = Out of memory?

Tags: gpu, memory-management

Strange, strange problem this one.

**Intro:**

I had cycles with these 2 GPU + CPU working well for renders.
Then, after some time, I took the 750ti out and continued working with only the 1070ti + CPU until after some time,
I put the 750ti back in and this problem appears.

[image]

[image]

**what I tried already:**

-install new gpu drivers

-try with experimental versions (inclusing 2.8)

**Important notes:**

The scene you see (my startup file), 
was rendering and previewing also before i took out the 750ti out the system

Comment: Did you set the two cards a SLI? If so disable it.

Comment: I don't think that is even possible as the two chipsets are different. but I checked anyway and there is no SLI enabling options in my nvidia control panel...

Comment: For SLI, you would disable it in the bios, it also has a connector you plug into the top of the cards to join them together. I think if it is active you will see SLI tuning options, not enable/disable but tuning options. So you had the 750 and added a 1070, took out the 750 and moved the 1070 to slot one, then put the 750 into slot two? They worked with the 750 in slot one but not with the 1070 in slot one?

Comment: checked and it is disabled in the bios and there is no tuning option in my nvidia control panel

Comment: I have the same problem with 2x K4000 cards in Blender 2.81 - we may have uncovered a bug! One K4000 with CPU works fine, adding a second one causes "out of memory" errors in an animation after a few frames. My cards are identical and work fine separately. I'll mention it to the Blender folks, if I find a solution I'll post it here.